# Debug Haxe from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, haxe

My goal is to debug Haxe application in Eclipse (publishing SWF) on Linux. I have manually installed Eclipse Helios, Flash debugger version and Haxe. I have installed Eclihx. Problem is that I'm getting message from Eclipse:

*Flash debug runner. This feature isn't ready!*

Note: I can run program, so Haxe compiling works. I have also tried adding `-D` and `-debug` to hxml. I've been Googling out there, but no success.

And also, I don't know how to setup Eclipse so when I do run that automatically browser pops up with html.

Comment: If the debugger already works with eclipse, you might just need to include -D fdb as a compile flag

Answer (score 3):

From what I know, it's not currently possible to debug Haxe from Eclipse. However, you could compile a debug Haxe build and and use Adobe's `fdb.exe`, which is the command line debugger for Flash. With it, you should be able to set breakpoints and do some run-time state inspection. Hope this helps!